# finding hyperlinks in a pdf file using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

Im getting an error while getting hyperlinks from PDF file in this line

```
PdfDictionary AnnotationAction = (PdfDictionary)AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A);
```

Getting below mention exception, somebody please help on this.

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference' to type
>   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
PdfDictionary AnnotationAction = (PdfDictionary)AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A);
```

please try

```
PdfDictionary AnnotationAction = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
```

In case of your document the value of the **/A** key does not seem to be a dictionary immediately but instead a reference to a dictionary. This reference has to be resolved. `GetAsDict` does this and the cast under the hood.